# Returning boolean value of comparing two lists

Tags: java

I found the following example that prints the similarities between  two lists. In fact I only want to return `true` if both lists have the same values or `false` otherwise. For example, the following code should return return false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);

    Set<Integer> similar = new HashSet<Integer>(list1);
    similar.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println("Similar  " + similar);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _return_? Do you want to move all this to a method that has a `boolean` return type and `return` a `boolean` value corresponding to the result of the comparison? What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Also, are you considering order, duplicates, etc.?

Comment: Maybe u want: `System.out.println("Similar  " + similar.retainAll(list2));`

Comment: Actually I am looking for **printing** true when exactly both lists have similar numbers as well as the same size. I will fix my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `List.equals`:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
    boolean test = list1.equals(list2);
    System.out.println("Similar  " + test);
}
}
```

So, `equals` from `List` will check if two lists are equal by full terms, same size and same values in it and on the same position. What you did with `HashSet` will only check if one list is subset of other list. However, if `list1` is subset of `list2` and `list2` is subset of `list1`, they are equal (by math). But, `List.equals()` is faster and you need less memory then creating two `Sets` and do subset operations.

However, `{1,2,3}` is equal to `{1,2,3}` but not to `{1,3,2}` in terms of `List.equals`. If you want to `{1,2,3}` be equal to `{1,3,2}` and to `{1,3,2,1,3}` then you do it with `Sets`:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2);

    Set<Integer> similar2 = new HashSet<Integer>(list2);
    Set<Integer> similar1 = new HashSet<Integer>(list1);
    boolean test = similar1.equals(similar2);
    System.out.println("Similar  " + test);
}
}
```

`Set.equals` works different then `List.equals`, since it checks if every element in `similar1` exists in `similar2` (by iteration), it doesn't care about the order. (Thank you @brso05 for pointing this out).

Comment: Thank you very much. This example prints true but it should print false because the two lists are not the same. I want to return true when exactly both lists have similar numbers as well as the same size .. I am a bit stuck for that

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: @AdnanIsajbegovic you should be able to do `similar2.equals(similar1);` with the sets and it should work even if the order isn't the same...But the way you are doing it should work also.

Comment: you are right, just saw the code, it will work same thing I wrote but in more efficient way.